# CakePHP Access function in current controller from appController

Tags: cakephp, controller

I have a function in the appController that needs to access a function in the current controller being called, if it exists. I can't figure out how to get at it...

In my appController's function I have:

```
$modelName = $this->modelClass;
$controllerName = Inflector::pluralize($modelName)."Controller";
$myVar = array(..., ..., ...);
```

And I've tried

```
$myVar = $$controllerName->modifyTable($myVar);
```

But that doesn't work.

Thoughts?

Comment: That looks really weird. How about `$this->modifyTable()`?

Comment: Move the functions you wish to share between multiple controllers to a component.

Comment: @Kai I'm not looking to use them in multiple places, I'm looking to define the function in a specific controller that I'm using to modify a universal function in AppController. Otherwise I'm copy-pastaing the entire function to every individual controller for the sake of changing one variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
public function whatever_name(){
    $modelName = $this->modelClass;
    $controllerName = Inflector::pluralize($modelName)."Controller";
    $myVar = array(..., ..., ...);
}
```

Then you may call it in your controller something like this :

```
$this->whatever_name();
```

If this doesn't work out, try to create a component or helper w/c I think it's more cleaner solution ;)

Comment: I'm trying to do the exact opposite - call the function in the AppController, not in the individual controller.